# How to ask servlet to stay in the previous page with out losing previous page data..?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

- I stored employee details in `memory not in DB by using Ajax`. after entering the records, if I press refresh button of the browser. All records will be gone. Only empty textboxes page will appear.
- Whenever we press refresh button, a Unique ID will go to the servlet, if it is a new one, the logic of servlet will execute otherwise the servlet will be able to display the previous web page with the previous content.
- I didn't use any framework. I used only servlet. How to accomplish this task?
  What I have tried:

**In my servlet "POST" method:**

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=null;    
HttpSession session=req.getSession();    
String GUID=req.getParameter("guid");       
String PrevGUID=(String) session.getAttribute("guid");      
System.out.println("-------------- GUID : "+GUID);     
System.out.println("-------------- PREV GUID : "+PrevGUID);   

if(GUID.equals(PrevGUID)){     
System.out.println("-------------- 1-Same GUID");  
dispatcher=req.getRequestDispatcher("DisplayDetails.jsp");       
dispatcher.forward(req, res);      
}         
else{        
System.out.println("-------------- 2-Diff GUID");                
session.setAttribute("guid",GUID);                         
doGet(req, res);                               
}
```

Instead of forwarding request in "if" loop, I want to display previous jsp page with previous data.
Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: You can send the rest of the data with the new GUID. Ignore the data later if you want.

Comment: i send that GUID with help of hidden box.,, and i send that required data by using another hidden variable .. but the second one was appeared as null value in servlet.... i dont know how to solve that one..

Comment: You need to post the relevant code!